WCF returning 400 error for a very simple application
I have created a very simple WCF application, doing nothing but returning the input value you put in.
When hosting this application in IIS locally, I get a response without any issue.
However, when putting this application on my Windows 2022 server, for all the request I do I directly receive an '400 Bad Request' error. No matter what I try to do.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
    }

And the implementation of GetData:
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}

The web config looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
    <system.diagnostics>  
        <sources>  
            <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"  
                    propagateActivity="true">  
                <listeners>  
                    <add name="traceListener"
                         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                         initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />  
                </listeners>  
            </source>  
        </sources>  
    </system.diagnostics>  

</configuration>


In the trace I have enabled I have an exception like:
                    <Exception>
                        <ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
                        <Message>There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.</Message>
                        <StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.ContinueReading(Int32 bytesRead)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.DecodeBufferedMessageAsync()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.BeginParse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.BeginParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginParseIncomingMessage(AsyncCallback asynCallback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult..ctor(ReplyChannelAcceptor acceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, HttpPipeline pipeline, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
                        <ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details. ---&amp;gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file.
   at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.ProcessBuffer(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.SetInput(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Encoding encoding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.UTF8BufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageData.GetMessageReader()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
                        <InnerException>
                            <ExceptionType>System.Xml.XmlException, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
                            <Message>Unexpected end of file.</Message>
                            <StackTrace>   at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.ProcessBuffer(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.SetInput(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Encoding encoding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.UTF8BufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageData.GetMessageReader()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)</StackTrace>
                            <ExceptionString>System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file.
   at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.ProcessBuffer(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.SetInput(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Encoding encoding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.UTF8BufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageData.GetMessageReader()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)</ExceptionString>
                        </InnerException>
                    </Exception>

"There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network" and then later in the exception: Unexpected end of file.
I have tried with the composer tool of Fiddler as well, this being my request:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetData>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:value>3</tem:value>
      </tem:GetData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

With headers:
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"

Which gives me also a 400 exception without any more info.
When I execute the URL in a browser: http://localhost/WcfTest/Service1.svc, I can see that the svc is loaded correctly.
Any clue what the cause of this issue can be?

Delete the <s:Header> in the request.


